# How to set value for a field of one list of object from another list of object having a common field?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am having 2 lists, let's say

```
1 -> List<Employee> list1;
2 -> List<Age> list2

class Employee {
    String name;
    String age;
    String address;
}

class Age {
    String name;
    String age;
}
```

What I like to do is I need to replace the age for all records in **Employee List** with the age in **Age List** having same **name** in both. How could I achieve this in Java 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can stream the `List<Age>` inside the iterating the items of `List<Employee>`:

```
list1.forEach(e -> e.setAge(
     list2.stream()                                     // Stream<Age>
          .filter(a -> a.getName().equals(e.getName())) // ... find the name match
          .map(Age::getAge)                             // ... extract the age
          .findAny().orElse("unknown")));               // ... return it or else "unknown"
```

- In case there is found no match of names, the default value is set to `unknown`.
- Also, you have to assure there are no duplicated names on which the age is based on.
- The age is `String` - is it okay?
- Are you sure there are no `null` values?

---

In case you want to remove such unmatched entries, I suggest you use rather `Iterator` with `Map<String, List<Age>>`:

```
Map<String, List<Age>> map = list2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(             // Map<String, List<Age>>
         Age::getName));                        // ... where 'name' is the key

final  Iterator<Employee> iterator = list1.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {                    // Iterating List<Employee>
    final Employee e = iterator.next();         // Employee
    if (map.containsKey(e.getName())) {         // If there is Age with equal 'name'
        final String age = map.get(e.getName()) // ... get the first found age
            .get(0).getAge();
        e.setAge(age);                          // ... set it to the Employee
    } else iterator.remove();                   // ... or else remove the Employee
}
```

Again care about the points I listed above. Moreover, if you don't want to use the first found age `map.get(e.getName()).get(0).getAge()`, you need to perform `Stream::reduce` over the `Stream<Age>` like:

```
// null doesn't occurunless the Age::getAge returns null
// The reducing would be much easier if the age is int
// Feel free to find max/min of the ages... up to you
String age = map.get(e.getName()).stream().map(Age::getAge).reduce(...).orElse(null);
```

---

Conclusion: The [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) way is a but clumsy and I, personally, would stick with the procedural for-loop approach.

Comment: What if no match for name is found in Employee list then we should delete that particular record from Employee list?

Comment: It's up to you. My solution, in that case, sets the age as `unknown`. You can either remove these entries (`Stream::filter`) or leave them with `unknown` age. It depends on the business logic you implement.

Comment: Could you please update the code with Stream:filter so as to remove those entries if no match found?

Comment: I updated my answer. Finally, the `Stream::filter` would require to iterate the list of `Age` twice (first to filter unmatched, second to map the new value), so I suggest you to use `Iterator`).

Answer (score 3):

This will work only if the `name` is unique.

Start by making a map from name to age:

```
Map<String,String> nameToAge = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getName, Item::getAge));
```

Now use `nameToAge` in your lookups:

```
List<String> names = list1.stream()
    .map(e -> new Employee(e.getName(), nameToAge.get(e.getName()), e.getAddress()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code assumes that your classes have properly encapsulated their properties, and that the `Employee` class has the appropriate constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `list2` for searching, you should create a HashMap. Because the ArrayList has O(n) performance for searching age by name from `list2`, whereas the HashMap `Map<String, String> ageWithName` has O(1) performance for searching on average.

`Function<Employee, String> findAge` takes employee as input and gives you the age:

```
Map<String, String> ageWithName = list2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Age::getName, Age::getAge));
Function<Employee, String> findAge = e -> ageWithName.get(e.getName());

list1.forEach(e -> e.setAge(findAge.apply(e)));
```

Answer (score 1):

A direct approach would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    Employee employee = list1.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
       Age age = list2.get(j);
       if (employee.name.equals(age.name)) {
           employee.age = age.age;
           list1.set(i, employee);
       }
    }
}
```

You can also implement an equals method in employee, and make use of list#indexOf

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    Employee employee = list1.get(i);
    int ageIndex = list2.indexOf(employee); //or list2.indexOf(employee.name);
    if (ageIndex != -1) {
       employee.age = list2.get(ageIndex).age;
       list1.set(i, employee);
    }
}
```